# How do you tell if a WPF Window is closed?

Tags: wpf

I'm working on an application that displays some child windows which can either be closed by the user or are automatically closed.  While debugging some exceptions that were being thrown, I discovered I was trying to call methods like `Hide()` on a window that had already been closed; this particular branch of code was common to both cases and I hadn't noticed this.

One of my first ideas was to look for a property on `Window` that would indicate the window had been closed.  I can't seem to find one.  In WinForms, I'd look to the *IsDisposed* property for a somewhat reliable indicator that the form had been closed (it won't reliably work for a dialog but I'm not working with dialogs.)  I don't see anything equivalent on `Window`.  The documentation for `Window.Close()` doesn't seem to indicate any properties that are changed by the method.  Am I missing something obvious, or is the only method to know if a window's been closed to handle the `Closed` event?  That seems kind of a harsh requirement for a simple task.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

According to [this conversation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c521ac47-7326-483a-be60-42de0e355711/) on the MSDN WPF forums (see the last post), you can check to see if the IsLoaded is false, which means that the window is "eligible" for unloading its content.  I hope that works for you!

Comment: This property cannot be accessed from another thread, and Invoking a call to the disposed Window block infinitely. So I ended up using my own instance variable for that and access it in a way that doesn't require synchronisation (isClosed = true at the beginning of the OnClosed method, then read it later again).

Comment: This doesn't work if events are still being processed. For example if a button Click handler closes a window and then opens another and the second window's initialization checks `IsLoaded` of the first, it will return `true`.

Comment: @nmclean agreed, I've had a case where WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle() throws an exception which states the window is closed, and yet window.IsLoaded = true.

Answer (score 24):

If you derive from the Window class, you can do this:

```
public bool IsClosed { get; private set; }

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
    IsClosed = true;
}
```

It has an advantage over registering for the Closed event - no need to un-register the callback.

Comment: How about when it gets opened a second time...

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque Set IsClosed = false when the window is opened.

Answer (score 11):

Hope this is useful for you:

PresentationSource.FromVisual(window) == null;

Answer (score 8):

My solution was to simply attach an event to the dialog's `Closed` event:

```
MikesDialog dlg = new MikesDialog();
dlg.Closed += delegate
{
    //  The user has closed our dialog.
    validationgDlg = null;
};

//  ...elsewhere in the code...

if (validationgDlg != null)
{
     //  Our "MikesDialog" is still open...
     . . .
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way : [Application.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) contains a list of open windows.
You can check is this collection contains your window (it is removed after closing).

Looks like you have to call `OfType<Window>()` because it is a specialized collection.

Comment: be careful with this one - this may sometimes contain windows that aren't closed, notably those that failed during initial display due to bad XAML

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why the *IsDisposed* property is internal, but if you don't fear reflection:

```
var window = new Window();
var propertyInfo = typeof(Window).GetProperty("IsDisposed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var isDisposed = (bool)propertyInfo.GetValue(window);
```

That being said, reflection is not to be overused because you're no longer protected by the public API of the class. Be sure to use at least unit tests if you go that route.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a non static property to the WindowClass `bool IsClosed`, and set true on the `Closed` event:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; } = false;
    public MyWindow()
    {
        Closed += MyWindow_Closed;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}    

private void MyWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   IsClosed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some occasions checking `Application.Current.MainWindow.IsActive` is enough