# How to determine if window is disposed

Tags: wpf

I have a function in a WPF MainWindow1.Xaml when application shuts down. But in unknown cases user can close application in another way then using the "file > close" button. I just need to know in the "Closing" methode if the current MainWindow1.xaml is already disposed or not. But I could not find any property.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(yourWindow)
```

If `source` is null or `source.IsDisposed == true`, that would indicate your Window has been closed.

Comment: `source.IsDisposed` will always be `false` since otherwise, `PresentationSource.FromVisual` won't return the source.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the `Closed` event on the `Window`. <strike>When this event is called the windows is closed</strike>. Actually I have to correct: According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed.aspx) it only means that you cannot prevent the window from closing when this event is called.
If listening to the `Closed` event is not good enough then this is another option: [How do you tell if a WPF Window is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381973/how-do-you-tell-if-a-wpf-window-is-closed)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ChrisWue. I will try it that way: ` <Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="SDKSample.App" ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown" /> ` with MainWindow1.IsLoaded property...

Comment: Does not work. See the situation here: [link](http://www.goldengel.ch/temp/WPF%20Window%20is%20closing%20disposing.png)

Comment: I think you are trying to call `Close` the window while it is already closing. I'm not sure what your goal is maybe you can explain more.