# How to know if Window Close was completed or cancelled?

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF Application.
Window1 can open `WindowA.Show(), WindowB.Show(), WindowC.Show()`

When we close Window1 we want to close all open windows as well (A, B and C).

On `Window1_Closing` event we call

```
WindowA.Close();
WindowB.Close();
WindowC.Close();
```

On window closing of any of these Cancel = true can be called and the WindowA (or B or C) won't close.
Then we don't want to close Window1 (the parent).
How to know in `Window1_Closing` if any of the child windows was cancelled (not closed)?

Comment: Is that `Window` a form?

Comment: can you not add a property to your child windows WindowA, etc...? Then on closing you can set it to either true or false depending if the closing got cancelled. In you application window you can then check that property and also cancel if necessary.

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid when I asked the question here. Finally I will do that if there is not solution supported by WPF.

Comment: see also [How do you tell if a WPF Window is closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381973/how-do-you-tell-if-a-wpf-window-is-closed)

Comment: Are there any other windows in your application? If there aren't, on Window1 close you can also Exit() the application and that will close all its children windows (A,B,C)

Comment: Thanks, Casper. Window1 is not the main window. It is just part of the application. We can't close the application by closing Window1.

Comment: @Serge - I tried this post first. The suggested solution didn't work. the IsLoaded was always true, so I would never be able to close the window...

Comment: @st_stefanov That is why in the comments someone says: So I ended up using my own instance variable for that and access it in a way that doesn't require synchronisation (isClosed = true at the beginning of the OnClosed method, then read it later again).

Comment: Why is it possible to cancel the closing of children windows (Cancel=true). Are you trying to prevent closing them? If yes, hide the close window button on them.

Comment: The Cancel of the sub windows can occur as validation result. Let's say they didn't fill in a mandatory field and are not allowed to exit the window. This is why we need to leave the user stay on the window until this is populated. And if the parent window is closed, then WindowA won't be valid anymore. We close either all or none.

Comment: Ok I got it, thx. Not the nicest design but if there are constraints you have to meet them.

Comment: You can use the Owner property of WindowA set to Window1, before showing WindowA. On Window1_Closing, check if its OwnedWindows count is greater than 0, to cancel the closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Window.Closed` event is fired after the window is closed. Either move your logic to eventhandler of Closed event, or use the event to send some flag:

   ```
   bool isClosed = false;
   WindowA.Closed += delegate { isClosed = true; };
   WindowA.Close();

   if (isClosed) { 
   }
   ```
2. `Application.Current.Windows` is collection of currently opened windows:

   ```
   WindowA.Close();
   bool isClosed = !Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Contains(WindowA);
   ```

Comment: @Serge, I implemented the solution that you suggested, it is also working fine. Thank you.